# TSQL split at closest new line under 8000 characters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, split, varchar, charindex

This may be simple but I'm no SQL Guru. I'm generating a list of items that need to be addressed by a human and sending that off in email format to the appropriate party. In most cases it's under 8000 chars but there have been a few times it's exceeded that number. The problem is that the stored proc that sends the email only takes 8000 chars for the email body. Thus my problem.

I can't change the send email proc because... Well I really don't know why. I was just told that I can't do that. Figure out something here...

Enough back story, to the issue at hand.

I want to split my varchar(max) at the last new line under 8000 characters.

Instead of:

Email 1
Item 1 needs attention! Do xyz.
Item 2 needs attention! Do xyz.
Item 3 needs attention! Do xyz.
Item 4 needs att

Email 2 
ention! Do xyz.
I want to split it nicely

Email 1
Item 1 needs attention! Do xyz.
Item 2 needs attention! Do xyz.
Item 3 needs attention! Do xyz.

Email 2
Item 4 needs attention! Do xyz.

How do I ask for the last CHARINDEX of a new line?

Answer (score 0):

I started typing up this question and apparently all I needed was to discuss it with someone. Thank you for being my unknowing ears. As I finished the last question above, something I read in my search earlier clicked and I figured out answer.

```
ELSE
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @EmailPart VARCHAR(8000)
            DECLARE @CurrentText VARCHAR(8000)
            DECLARE @CurrentPosition BIGINT = 0

            WHILE @CurrentPosition < len(@EmailBody)
            BEGIN
                SET @EmailPart = SUBSTRING(@EmailBody + CHAR(13), @CurrentPosition, 8000)

                SET @CurrentText = left(@EmailPart, Len(@EmailPart) - PatIndex('%' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + '%', REVERSE(@EmailPart)))
                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + len(@CurrentText)    

                EXEC .dbo.spSendMail @to = @EmailList
                        ,@cc = @AppCCList --rfc 1/16/15
                        ,@subj = 'Ordering Issues'
                        ,@body = @EmailBody
            END
        END
```

So, lets break that down a bit.

Give me the block of text I wan to work on. 8000 character max. Just realized the + CHAR(13) may need to go on the outside of the SUBSTRING but I'll worry about that later. You get the idea...

```
SET @EmailPart = SUBSTRING(@EmailBody + CHAR(13), @CurrentPosition, 8000)
```

Now that I have the no more than 8000 char limit taken care of, lets get the last line break. CHAR(13) and CHAR(10) are line break and carriage return. (I don't remember which is which atm but Google does.)

```
left(@EmailPart, Len(@EmailPart) - PatIndex('%' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + '%', REVERSE(@EmailPart)))
```

This is the magic that finds the last line break, in this case double line break because it looked better with my source data.

```
PatIndex('%' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + '%', REVERSE(@EmailPart))
```

We're finding the index of a pattern of line breaks and carriage returns in the 8000 char string that has been reversed.

That gives us how many characters the index is from the end of the string. We then take the length of the string minus that index to find the index from the front of the string.

```
Len(@EmailPart) - PatIndex(/*snipped for clarity*/)
```

Once we have that. I simply take the Left x characters where x is the result of the above difference.

```
left(@EmailPart, Len(@EmailPart) - PatIndex(/*snipped for clarity*/))
```

The rest of it is just keeping track of how many characters you've taken and looping through the main body.

Hopefully this is useful to someone.